# how to trigger a hover and animate the div

Tags: jquery, html, css

I want to use hover and make my div become longer with animation

what is wrong with this?
UPDATE:No result with doc again

```
 <html>
    <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $("div").hover(function(){
        $(this).animate({ width: "200px" });
    }, function() {
        $(this).animate({ width: "100px" });
    });
    }
    </script>
    <style>
    div.ex
    {
    width:20px;
    padding:10px;
    background-color:gray;
    margin:0px;
    }
    </style>
    </head>
    <body>
    <form>
    <div class="ex"></div>
    </form>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Why not use the latest version? `<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>`

Comment: You have a bad closing `}` of doc ready handler, change to this `});` and all be fine then.

Comment: What happens when you try to run it? What have you tried in order to debug it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to wrap your code in `doc ready` handler:

```
$(function(){
   $("div").hover(function(){
      $(this).animate({ width: "200px" });
   }, function() {
      $(this).animate({ width: "100px" });
   });
});
```

This

```
$(function(){
  ......
});
```

and this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   .......
});
```

Both are same.

#### As per your updated code:

If you take a look at your closing tag `}` of `doc ready` it still misses a proper closing`});`

```
});
}
```

Comment: yes I forgot the doc but again no result

Comment: You have a bad closing } of doc ready handler, change to this }); and all be fine then.

Comment: @nikparsa Thanks, but don't know why got a downvote by some one. Thanks anyway.

Comment: I don't know either but I was downvoted too! but I don't know where?!

Answer (score 1):

Wrap your code in ready()

```
 $(function(){
       $("div").hover(function(){
           $(this).animate({ width: "200px" });
       }, function() {
          $(this).animate({ width: "100px" });
       });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

**You are not closing the function bracket.**

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
$("div").hover(function(){
    $(this).animate({ width: "200px" });
}, function() {
    $(this).animate({ width: "100px" });
});
} <---- you are missing ')'
```

Change your code like below

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("div").hover(function(){
    $(this).animate({ width: "200px" });
}, function() {
    $(this).animate({ width: "100px" });
});
});
```

[Demo](http://jsbin.com/okovup/1/edit)